# Test two sequential okhttp calls with junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a public method:

```
public class methodUnderTest() {
     A();
     B();
}
```

and two private methods:

```
private class A() {
     ...
     okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
     ...
}

private class B() {
     ...
     okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
     ...
}
```

I want to test the method `methodUnderTest` but I don't know how to mock the okHttp calls. I have mocked the first call (from class A) and their response but will be overridden by the second call from class B (eg. response for call from class A will be the response corespondent from class B).
It is possible to differentiate the calls from each class ?

```
//inside the test method [with pesudocode]:
// for class A
ResponseA = response.body({"id":"1"});
when(call.execute()).thenReturn(response1);                               
when(okkHttpClient.newCall(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(call);

// for class B
ResponseB = response.body({"type"="car"});
when(call.execute()).thenReturn(responseB);               
when(okkHttpClient.newCall(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(call);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could chain `thenReturn` for your `call.execute()`

```
Response responseA = ;
Response responseB = ;

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = mock(OkHttpClient.class);
Call call = mock(Call.class);

when(call.execute()).thenReturn(responseA).thenReturn(responseB);
when(okHttpClient.newCall(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(call);
```

Now your mocked call should return responseA on the first invocation and responseB for other invocations.